# .resjson in C# XAML store app

Tags: c#, localization, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to use resjson format instead of resw for xaml/c# store apps?

In my scenario I have large json files that are already translated.  I find the json format easier to work with so I'd prefer to work with json files instead of resw.  I know the multilingual toolkit works, but right now I'm getting empty strings when using the resjson format with x:Uid or directly with resource loader.

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
string text = loader.GetText("HelloWorld/Text");
```

Text comes out as empty string.

However, I'm able to see the strings via this:

```
var map = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("/resources");

var list  = map.Keys.ToList();

string val = map.GetValue("Greeting.Text").ValueAsString;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great news!  You can use .resjson in c# xaml store app along with the multilingual toolkit.

The trick to getting x:Uid working was that in the resjson file you need to define the keys with / instead of .

my .resjson just had one key in it as "Greeting/Text"  and then I was able to refer to it in my xaml file as

```
<Run x:Uid="Greeting" />
```